# How to deal with WiFi signal noise?

Tags: wireless-router, ping

I am not sure, if this is the right place where to ask such a question.

Short version: When connected to my WiFi router, the response is very slow.

Long version: In my house, I have a WiFi router (5+ years old TP-Link). When I connect to it via cable and I ping it I can see responses like <1ms. When I connect to it via WiFi then sometimes I see responses like 3-10ms (which I would expect), but sometimes something happens (I am imagining neighbor turning his microwave on or something like that) and my responses go all the way high to the 200-500+ ms zone. Router and device are like 2 meters apart.

Initially I suspected my iPad being old and broken. After rearranging stuff in our rooms, I had to connect my work laptop to WiFi too and I saw the same behavior. Thus, I suspected my WiFi router. Tried rebooting, upgrading firmware, nothing helped. So I bought another WiFi router (another TP Link, WR-840N, kept default settings) and again, same behavior. The last thing on my mind is some kind of noise disrupting my WiFi signal. Am I on the right track? If so, what can I do about it? If not, what can I do about it?

Any help appreciated.

Sidenote. There seems to be a pattern in the responses, like every even ping is ok, while odd takes long.

[image: ping]

Comment: Change to a different channel ( 2.4GHz) or switch to 5.0 GHz to avoid the microwave interferance all together.

Comment: That sounds good. Are all routers capable of doing it? I clicked through wireless settings and didn't find anything similar. My model is TP-LINK WE840N, if it helps. Edit: I'm blind. I can see channel width auto/20MHz/40MHz, and then auto/1/2/.../13. Is that the right settings?

Comment: As Ramhoud pointed out, if you use the 2.4 Ghz range, stick to challens 1, 6 or 11, but note that 11 is actually in range of devices such as wireless phones (not mobiles, but those for households) You would not want to use any of the other channels because that would create overlap. You can scan your surroundings with a wifi scanner to get the best channel.

Comment: @Erlik yes, all routers are capable of changing the channel. Note, most of the time its set to Auto. If so, just set it to 1, 6 or 11 manually. Preferably 1 or 6 as I suspect 11 is causing interference.

Comment: Are all routers capable of doing what specifically?  Changing the channel, sure, if there firmware provides that option.  Support 5.0 GHz and 2.4GHz that is a hardware feature.  The only question I decided I could answer, was,  **If so, what can I do about it?** since you didn't provide the model of the replacement router.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll try that out. Was it that obvious that it doesn't even deserve being an answer? :)

Comment: The pattern of every other ping taking 40-50 times longer seems to indicate your router is somehow not able to process requests that fast (i.e. it's needing more time for every second ping). If it was interference I would not expect this pattern but something more random.

Comment: @Erlik - I don't see an answer I can even answer to be honest.

Comment: Apparently, it affected the output. I went through all the channels and sometimes it was better, sometimes worse. Definitely, it solved the issue for me.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the name "WE840N" correctly?

Comment: I am sorry, it's "R", not "E".. Hardware Version: WR840N v2 00000000